# How to verify that $a\cdot b \times c = b\cdot c \times a = c\cdot a \times b$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Given that **a** = **i** + $2$**j** + $3$**k**, **b** = $2$**i** - **j** and **c** = **j** - $2$**k**, verify that **a**$\cdot$**b** $\times$ **c** = **b**$\cdot$**c** $\times$ **a** = **c**$\cdot$**a** $\times$ **b**.

So I took
**a**$\cdot$**b** $\times$ **c** = $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\-2\\\end{matrix}\right)=0$

However,  **b**$\cdot$**c** $\times$ **a**  doesn’t seem to yield the same value as **a**$\cdot$**b** $\times$ **c** .

**b**$\cdot$**c** $\times$ **a** $=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\0\\\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\1\\-2\\\end{matrix}\right)\times\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{matrix}\right)$= $-1 \left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{matrix}\right)$

Did I multiply anything wrong?

Comment: When one result is a scalar, and the other is a vector, then yes - you did something wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get a final result of $16$ for all the products. Your result of a vector for $\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf c×\mathbf a$ is wrong – for expressions of this type *the cross product must be performed first*.

Comment: So I should do it like this: b$\cdot$(c$\times$a)?

Comment: @gc3941d Yes. This special kind of product, called the triple product, is also the determinant of the matrix whose columns are $\mathbf{a,b,c}$ in that order.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel also the volume of parallelepiped with vertices $a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c$ and the origin if $a,b,c$ are clockwise when viewed from the origin and its negative value otherwise